# How to replace only a column and for the rows contains specific values

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I have the file with | delimited, and am trying to perform below logic

```
cat list.txt

101
102
103

LIST=`cat list.txt`
```

Input file

```
1|Anand|101|1001    
2|Raj|103|1002    
3|Unix|110|101
```

Expected result

```
1|Anand|101|1001    
2|Raj|103|1002    
3|Unix|UNKNOWN|101
```

I tried 2 methods,

1. using `fgrep` by passing list.txt as input and tried to segregate as 2 files. One matches the list and second not matching and post that non matching file using awk & `gsub` replacing the 3rd column with UNKNOWN, but issue here is in 3rd row 4th column contains the value available in list.txt, so not able to get expected result
2. Tried using one liner awk by passing list in -v VAR. Here no changes in the results.

```bash
awk -F"|" -v VAR="$LIST" '{if($3 !~ $VAR) {{{gsub(/.*/,"UNKNOWN", $3)1} else { print 0}' input_file
```

Can you please suggest me how to attain the expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `cat` to read complete file in a variable.

You may just use this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}
!($3 in a) {$3 = "UKNNOWN"} 1' list.txt input_file

1|Anand|101|1001
2|Raj|103|1002
3|Unix|UKNNOWN|101
```

Comment: tried the logic as mentioned, what i can get the results like, changes are not happening as expected, UNKNOWN is getting updated for all the rows and dummy records are getting added with all the values in list in column 1 and UNKNOWN in column 3, rest of the column are blank

Comment: Everything is working fine with the samples you have provided. Make sure your input files don't have DOS line breaks (check with command `cat -A file`). If it still doesn't work then provide sample files for which problem can be reproduced.